# How to remove Namespace and Nillable properties in generated XML by marshalling through JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have following XSD file:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="emp" targetNamespace="emp"
   elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
   <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Case_Detail" minOccurs="0"/>
   </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Case_Detail">
   <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="Central_Case_ID"/>
    <xs:element ref="Agency_Case_ID"/>
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="Central_Case_ID">
    <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="Agency_Case_ID">
   <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>  
    </xs:schema>
```

I have generated JAXB classes and trying to marshal into XML file. In generated XML file, I can for each elements in XML file, attributes are coming if it is null like :-
For e.g. :-

```
<Central_Case_ID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

My requirement is to have elements without these attributes at all even if some element has null values in the enitre XML file. For this I have tried alot, I made lot of changes in XSD like updated elementFormDefault="unqualified" and arguementFormDefault to unqalified but it didn't work. Then I made changes in @annotations in JAXB classes and also tried to set some properties in marshalling object like No_Namespace_schema_location but nothing worked.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Java Model

I generated the default Java model from your XML Schema using XJC.

### Demo Code

**Demo**

The demo code below populates the object model (setting the `centralCaseID` property to `null`) and marshals it to XML.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("emp");

        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        Root root = objectFactory.createRoot();

        CaseDetail caseDetail = objectFactory.createCaseDetail();
        caseDetail.setCentralCaseID(null);
        root.getCaseDetail().add(caseDetail);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="emp">
    <Case_Detail/>
</root>
```

Items to note:

- A namespace declaration was written out.  This is because the `@XmlSchema` annotation is present on the `package-info` class that maps the namespace qualification (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html).

  ```
  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
      namespace = "emp", 
      elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
  package emp;
  ```
- The element corresponding to the `centralCaseID` property does not appear in the XML.  This is the default behaviour regarding `null` properties (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html).